# Equations not properly horizontally-aligned with multicols from multicol

Tags: multicol

I want to show two equations in two columns in a document. Using multicols with the following code compiling with LuaLaTex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
% Load of many other packages

\begin{document}

% Text

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \[k_{t}=\alpha mc_{t}\frac{y_{t}}{r_{t}}\]
  \break
  \[y_{t}^{L}=(1-\alpha)mc_{t}\frac{y_{t}}{p_{t}^{L}}\]
\end{multicols}

% Text

\end{document}
```

compiles like this:

[image]

Note that the second equation is not in the same exact horizontal alignment as the first one, since it is slightly further below, even though there is plenty of space. What should I do in order to make them be aligned properly in the same horizontal line?

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but have you considered not having columns and just doing `\begin{align*} k_{t}&=\alpha mc_{t}\frac{y_{t}}{r_{t}} & y_{t}^{L}&=(1-\alpha)mc_{t}\frac{y_{t}}{p_{t}^{L}}\end{align*}` (with amsmath loaded) to have the two equations side by side aligned? (You could put three `&`s between them if you want them a little further apart.)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your screenshot on a fully up-to-date MaCTeX2022 system -- LuaHBTeX 1.15.0, LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 1, multicol 2021/11/30 v1.9d. Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when did you last update it?

Comment: With recent MiKTeX (LuaHBTeX, Verson 1.15.0 (MiKTeX 22.3)) I cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: Take a look at this question-answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298162/how-do-you-place-texts-side-by-side

Comment: @Mico I'm using compiling it in Overleaf,  with compiler LuaLatex and Tex Live version: 2020. Nevertheless, reproducing the code myself with the example I gave I'm also unable to reproduce this misalignment, probably because the entire context of the document is needed.

Comment: The previous comment was also for @Zarko

Comment: @frabjous This actually works fine for this case. Do you know if there's a way to use this method for expressing two equations in two columns with each equation being numbered?

Comment: This should be helpful regarding the vertical positioning: [Spurious space above `align` environment at top of page/`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954)

Answer (score 2):

The OP asked in a comment,

> Do you know if there's a way to [place] two equations in two columns with each equation being numbered?

There's no need for the considerable overhead that's associated with setting up a two-column page layout. Instead, just place 2 `minipage` environments, each of width `0.5\textwidth`, next to each other, and place an `equation`-like environment in each `minipage`.

[image]

In the above screenshot, there's zero separation between the `minipage`s. If you prefer a horizontal separation of, say, `0.1\textwidth`, all you'd have to do is set the widths of the `minipage`s to `0.45\textwidth` and insert an `\hfill` directive at the end of the first `minipage`:

[image]

---

Here's the code that generates the first screenshot:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % draw framelines around textblock

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
  k_{t}=\alpha mc_{t}\frac{y_{t}}{r_{t}}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}%   <-- the '%' symbol assures zero separation
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
  y_{t}^{L}=(1-\alpha)mc_{t}\frac{y_{t}}{p_{t}^{L}}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{equation}
    \omega^{2} = g k \tanh{\left(kh\right)}
    \label{eq:dispersion}
  \end{equation}\vspace{-6mm}
  \begin{equation}
    \lambda = \frac{g T^{2}}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi h}{\lambda}\right)
\label{eq:dispersion-lambda}
  \end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: \vspace{-6mm} does the trick